# XSLT, Python insert a python list of tuples on xslt attributes?

Tags: python, xml, xslt, attributes, tuples

I have the following problem: I want to extend the img element from an XML source with the attributes 'width' and 'height' in an XSLT transformation. The values of the attributes should be read from a Python list of tuples (the list consists of 2-tuples). The number of img elements in the XML source corresponds with the number of tuples in the list. 
The aim is to display the images differently in the target document of an XSL-FO transformation, depending on the size, resolution and aspect ratio (I´m using Apache FOP, can´t use Antenna).
I tried a solution with a regex replacement in Python, but can't get any further.

Here is my regex-line, after I have opened the source document an read it with read() in python.

```
doc = re.sub(r'(<v:imagedata\.*?\.jpg")', r'\1 width="{value-of tuple-data}" height="{value-of tuple-data}"', str(doc))
```

I don't know how to insert the values in the replacing pattern. Can I do this with iterating over two lists? But regex in XML-files is not a very good idea. That doesn't seem to be the right way. I know there are Python extensions for XSLT. But this seems quite complex. Maybe my problem is easier to solve, but I don't see it. In which direction do I have to think further?  I am happy about help.

**EDIT**

The source file is large and deeply nested (wordML).
The lines I want to transform are like:

```
 <v:imagedata src="bilder_web/image123.jpg"/>
```

And here is a sample line of the list of tuples

```
[(840,330),(328,301),(1087,189),(744,600),...]
```

where first value is width, second = height.

XSLT-Result should be:

```
<v:imagedata src="bilder_web/image123.jpg" width="first value-of tuple, e.g. 840" height="second value-of tuple, e.g. 330"/>
```

and so on.

Comment: Can you add more code than just the regex line? Like sample xml input, list of tuples, and sample of resulting xsl-fo?

Comment: XSLT does not know what a "Python list of tuples" is. But it can tokenize a *string* passed to it as parameter, and match the position of a token in the string to the position of `img` element in the XML document.

Comment: @michael.hor257k This could lead me to a solution, I think, but I did not complete understand this comment. Could you please describe it more detailed? Tokenizing is clear to me. But how would I pass the list of tuples as a string to XSLT? With a param-Attribute? And how do I match the position of the token correlating to the img element?

Comment: @DanielHaley I edited my question with more samples. I provided a XSLT-snippet as sample for result (no XSL-FO, because what I need here is a prepared XML-file (with XSLT) as source for XSL-FO)

Comment: You pass the parameter as part of calling the XSL transformation from your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following simplified example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <chapter id="1">
        <imagedata src="a.jpg"/>
        <para>
            <imagedata src="b.jpg"/>
            <imagedata src="c.jpg"/>
        </para>
        <para>
            <imagedata src="d.jpg"/>
        </para>
    </chapter>
    <chapter id="2">
        <para>
            <imagedata src="e.jpg"/>
            <imagedata src="f.jpg"/>
        </para>
        <imagedata src="g.jpg"/>
    </chapter>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (+ assuming support for EXSLT `str:tokenize()` extension function)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="image-dimensions-string"></xsl:param> 
<xsl:variable name="image-dimensions" select="str:tokenize($image-dimensions-string, ';')" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="imagedata">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="count(preceding::imagedata) + 1" />
    <xsl:variable name="dimensions" select="str:tokenize($image-dimensions[$i], ',')" />
    <imagedata src="{@src}" width="{$dimensions[1]}" height="{$dimensions[2]}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is called with a string parameter named `image-dimensions-string` containing:

```
100,150;200,250;300,350;400,450;500,550;600,650;700,750
```

the result will be:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <chapter id="1">
    <imagedata src="a.jpg" width="100" height="150"/>
    <para>
      <imagedata src="b.jpg" width="200" height="250"/>
      <imagedata src="c.jpg" width="300" height="350"/>
    </para>
    <para>
      <imagedata src="d.jpg" width="400" height="450"/>
    </para>
  </chapter>
  <chapter id="2">
    <para>
      <imagedata src="e.jpg" width="500" height="550"/>
      <imagedata src="f.jpg" width="600" height="650"/>
    </para>
    <imagedata src="g.jpg" width="700" height="750"/>
  </chapter>
</root>
```

Comment: Perfect! The transformation worked right away. I only had to switch from Saxon to Xalan as XSLT processor because Saxon (PE, EE) does not support the str.tokenize function of EXSLT as far as I can see.

Comment: Saxon supports XSLT 2.0 which has a native tokenize() function. I assumed you were using libxslt because of the Python tag.

Comment: Ok, didn´t know that. So I can switch back to Saxon.